# SConscript in different directory to source files

Tags: scons

I'm building code with multiple environments, outputting to multiple target directories.  The natural way to manage this seems to be with variant directories.  So I might want to build the same set of files multiple times with different options and different VariantDirs.  So I want to be able to have multiple SConscript files in different locations, all referring back to the same source directory.

One option I've tried is to do this:

```
SConstruct
src/test.cpp
src/magic/SConscript
```

This is my SConstruct:

```
env = Environment()

SConscript('src/magic/SConscript',
    variant_dir = 'build/src',
    src_dir = 'src',
    exports={'env':env},
    duplicate=0)
```

and this is src/magic/SConscript:

```
Import('env')

source = 'test.cpp'

env.Object(source)
```

I get this output:

```
scons: *** [build/src/magic/test.o] Source `src/magic/test.cpp' not found, needed by target `build/src/magic/test.o'.
```

This looks like both the `variant_dir` and `src_dir` are not being respected by `Object`, since neither mention `magic` at all.

Have I misunderstood how variant_dir/src_dir are meant to work, and what is the best way to build the same set of files with different targets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file/folder hierarchy doesn't fit the build specification in your SConstruct/SConscript files.
Note how file paths in SCons are usually relative to the location of the current SConscript, so:

```
source = 'test.cpp'
env.Object(source)
```

in `src/magic/SConscript` gets expanded to `src/magic/test.cpp`...which obviously doesn't exist. You could use `../test.cpp` as filename, or move the SConscript one up from `src/magic` to the `src` folder directly.

Some further remarks:

1.) When you specify a path for the name of the SConscript file in the SConscript call:

```
SConscript('src/SConscript',
    variant_dir = 'build',
    exports={'env':env},
    duplicate=0)
```

SCons will automatically derive the `src_dir` argument from the path of the first argument.

2.) Please check out the chapter 14 "Hierarchical Builds" in the UserGuide ( http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html ).

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you're right.  I was looking at the documentation here: https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/SConscript(), but I guess it's out of date.  The src_dir argument appears to be completely ignored.  So I can't see any way to do what I need...have multiple SConscript files with different options for the same files.  I may need to call the same SConscript file multiple times with different arguments passed in.

Comment: Actually, I think a better solution may be to have multiple SConscript files in the source directory, with different names. I'll try that tomorrow.  Thanks!

Comment: Just call the same SConscript with a different Environment each time. Check out https://bitbucket.org/dirkbaechle/scons_talks and there especially `scons_talks/pyconde_2013/examples/exvar/` for a working example.