# scons fails to resolve relative source path

Tags: scons

I have the following project structure:

```
/prj
    SConstruct
    /src
        /app
        /lib1
        /lib2
        /...
```

'/prj/src/lib1' structure:

```
/lib1
    /src
    /test
    SConscript
```

'lib1/SConscript':

```
SConscript('test/test1/SConscript',
            exports = 'env',
            variant_dir = '#build/release/lib1/test', 
            duplicate = 0)
```

and, finally, 'test' directory:

```
/test
    /common
        helpers.cpp
    /test1
        SConscript
        main.cpp
```

In 'test/test1/SConscript' sources specified as:

```
Sources = ['../common/helpers.cpp', 'main.cpp']
```

Result:

```
scons: *** [build/release/lib1/common/helpers.o] 
Source `build/release/lib1/common/helpers.cpp' not found, 
needed by target `build/release/lib1/common/helpers.o'
```

As can be seen the problem is that scons tries to find out the source file 'helpers.cpp' in build directory, not in source one.

Some research shows that the problem raised when source file path begins with '../'. When all sources defined underneath 'SConscript' file all is Ok.

Scons v2.5.1 and v3.0.1 demonstrate the same behavior.

What I did wrong? I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33486245/8955526) where the author advised:

> You could use ../test.cpp as filename

but I doing exactly the same. Is such scons behavior intended or this is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Your "code" in "`lib1/SConscript`":

```
SConscript('test/test1/SConscript',
            exports = 'env',
            variant_dir = '#build/release/lib1/test', 
            duplicate = 0)
```

uses the name of the given "`test/test1/SConscript`" and implicitly links the folder "`test/test1`" as "variant folder" (=variant_dir) to the target directory "`#build/release/lib1/test`". So if a required file can't be found in "`#build/release/lib1/test`", *SCons* tries to do an alternative "lookup" in "`test/test1/`". But this link is not automatically set for the "`common`" folder as well, and that's why the lookup of the "`helpers.cpp`" fails. This is the intended behaviour and correct in *SCons*.

A solution for your current problem would be to move the "`test/test1/SConscript`" one folder level higher, include the sources there as "`common/helpers.cpp`" and "`test/main.cpp`" and call this new SConscript from "`lib1/SConscript`" as:

```
SConscript('test/SConscript',
            exports = 'env',
            variant_dir = '#build/release/lib1/test', 
            duplicate = 0)
```

Comment: Yes, I have fixed the problem just as you offer (your post raises up my understanding of the problem, thank you). The only drawback is that in this case I'm forced to put definitions for all test subprojects in the same SConscript file located at 'test' directory level. This can be inconvenient in case of a lot of tests and more important - such approach couples building of all test projects instead of ability to build any test binary separately.

Comment: 1) You can specify a single (or several) targets as arguments on the command-line: "`scons build/.../testa build/.../testb`". 2) You can have several SConscripts and select between them via "`scons -f SConscript.testa`" for example. 3) Project setups, like the one you gave as example above, always benefit from creating a separate library from you sources in "common". Then you can add this to the LIBS variable of the Environment, and simply build your test programs themselves. It doesn't get anymore lightweight than this, I guess. Just to give you some further ideas. ;)

Comment: Creating library from 'common' sources is nice idea, thanks! Do I understand correctly that file with leading '../' in its path is not a problem for scons? I.e. if, for example, a project uses header file (with Q_OBJECT macro) that located at several levels above (main project include directory), scons will correctly resolve 'variant_folder' and launch moc for this file?

Comment: Yes, leading "`../`" shouldn't be a problem...as long as the resulting path is a subfolder of the directory where the top-level SConstruct is in. See also #2 of our [most-frequently-asked FAQs](http://scons.org/faq.html) (top of page, "How do I install files?").